# Understanding the relations without the knowledge of Plucker relations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, grassmannians

Consider the grassmannian $\mathrm{Gr}(2,5)$. We know there is an embedding of $\mathrm{Gr}(2,5)$ into $\mathbb{P}^9$ by using the 10 Plucker coordinates, and they satisfy 5 Plucker relations. And, so the coordinate ring of $\mathrm{Gr}(2,5)$ is the polynomial ring in these Plucker coordinates, modulo the ideal generated by these 5 Plucker relations.

But, say as a novice I don't know about the Plucker relations, dimension or degree, then how do I prove that these 5 relations are a minimal set of generators for the ideal of relations? How do I prove that there are no other relations?

**Edit** I'm looking for a down-to-earth reasoning. Something like- I start with some relation, and then I'm able to prove that it belongs to the ideal generated by these 5 Plucker relations.

Comment: This is a strange question. Proving that the Plücker relations define the Grassmannian is straightforward linear algebra — you won't find more down-to-earth.

Comment: @abx Do you have any reference where I can read about the approach using linear algebra?

Comment: If Bourbaki doesn't frighten you, the treatment in *Algebra* III, §11 is excellent.